# Notepad++ add number in each line Ascending

Tags: notepad++

I have the following data in a text file

```
text
text
text
text
text
text
text
text
```

i use Notepad++ now

How would I change it to

```
1 text
2 text
3 text
4 text
1 text
2 text
3 text
4 text
```

Comment: This is not a job for text editor, write a script in your favorite scripting language. Read one line, prefix with the value needed, write the modified line. Done.

Comment: Then I have to look for someone who can make something like this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

:-)
I don't know what you are going to do, and I don't know how often you will have this scenario, but the easiest way for me is:
Copy the whole text to MS Word and then search and replace (+):
Search for blanks   and replace them with `^p`. `^p` sets a paragraph line-break. Then select all the needed text with + and add an enumeration (1. , 2., 3., 4), and make this again. Then copy it all over again to Notepad++ and search and replace (+):
Search for `.\t` (this is a TAB) and replace it with a blank  .
Then search for line-breaks  `\r\n` and you have your result `1 text 2 text 3 text 4 text 1 text 2 text 3 text 4 text`  (copied from my Notepad++).

I know this is somekind of "handmade", but it goes pretty fast, also for much longer texts.

If you want to have this feature in Notepad++ then you could write an own (Python...)-Script and put it on a button in Notepad++.
There are many PlugIns available for Notepad++, so you may extend Notepad++ Features to your needs or use existing solutions for your specific problem
See for example http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/
With this plugin you may run Python-Code extending Notepad++.
For your problem the Python-script would be pretty easy, and you could put it on an own button in Notepad++

Cheers
Bartek

Comment: I actually have to do this quite often 2 times a month and 50000 lines, so I had hoped there was a quick option haha. thanks for your comment.

Comment: 50000 lines is something that you didn't mention...that is a size for which my handmade is total rubbish, sure. But if you place an example of the file, maybe somebody has already a solution for this. If there are new lines in your "text" then it will be very difficult...